# Kernel Panics during and after 10.10.3 update

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

I have recently experienced two Kernel Panics on my MacBook Pro (13 inch, mid-2012). The first one happened during the upgrade process to 10.10.3 right at the end. The second happened today while browsing the web. Apple Hardware Test and Memtest turned up nothing. An Apple support rep guided me through deleting chaches, lauchdeamons, startup items and some other stuff. Can anyone tell from the logs pasted below what the cause of the problem might be? Given the timing, could it be something to do with the 10.10.3 update?

**First Report (end of upgrade to 10.10.3):**

```
Anonymous UUID:       2F268169-983A-6C24-0051-DA8D97195C57

Wed Apr  8 19:37:02 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff802f61a46e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802f593078, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff81392d4ff8, CR3: 0x00000000110f8028, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffffffffffffff, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff81392d5000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff81388b3b10, RBP: 0xffffff81388b3b70, RSI: 0xffffff8052c9a044, RDI: 0xffffff802fcd9904
R8:  0xffffff80421ec5b0, R9:  0xfffffffffffff000, R10: 0xffffff80421ec5a0, R11: 0xffffff8042226ba0
R12: 0xffffff802fcd9904, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff8052c9a000, R15: 0x0000000000000003
RFL: 0x0000000000010296, RIP: 0xffffff802f593078, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff81392d4ff8, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81388b37c0 : 0xffffff802f52fe41 
0xffffff81388b3840 : 0xffffff802f61a46e 
0xffffff81388b3a00 : 0xffffff802f636683 
0xffffff81388b3a20 : 0xffffff802f593078 
0xffffff81388b3b70 : 0xffffff802f5938be 
0xffffff81388b3bd0 : 0xffffff802f5bf8f0 
0xffffff81388b3c10 : 0xffffff802f5bf65e 
0xffffff81388b3c40 : 0xffffff802f5b6a95 
0xffffff81388b3c80 : 0xffffff802f5b063a 
0xffffff81388b3d90 : 0xffffff802f5a697c 
0xffffff81388b3dc0 : 0xffffff802f5523d7 
0xffffff81388b3e00 : 0xffffff802f9c16ff 
0xffffff81388b3e70 : 0xffffff802f9d8fc2 
0xffffff81388b3ef0 : 0xffffff802f9d9497 
0xffffff81388b3f30 : 0xffffff802f52c376 
0xffffff81388b3f60 : 0xffffff802f61ab8e 
0xffffff81388b3f80 : 0xffffff802f63664f 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: blued

Mac OS version:
14C1514

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Thu Feb 26 19:26:47 PST 2015; root:xnu-2782.10.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 270413F7-3B44-3602-894F-AC0D392FCF8E
Kernel slide:     0x000000002f200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802f400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802f300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 127759270563011
last loaded kext at 117432601792451: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7fb1e00000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 117493781525860: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7fb1e00000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.3
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   910.26.12
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  262.33.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.6.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B09, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: My Passport 0748
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: USB to Serial-ATA bridge
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

**Second report (browsing the web with Firefox):**

```
Anonymous UUID:       2F268169-983A-6C24-0051-DA8D97195C57

Mon Apr 27 14:59:15 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8002617cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8447c6ff, type 6=invalid opcode, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000010cac1008, CR3: 0x00000001f5f670f4, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff8002c80020, RBX: 0xffffff810b84b8a8, RCX: 0xffffff802e4a1b00, RDX: 0x0000000000002000
RSP: 0xffffff810b84b828, RBP: 0xffffff810b84b890, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0x0000000013000001
R8:  0xffffff8020ce00c0, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff8013e4e168
R12: 0x0000000000000850, R13: 0xffffff8002c80020, R14: 0xffffff80244ab2d0, R15: 0x0000000013000001
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f8447c6ff, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x000000010cac1008, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810b84b4d0 : 0xffffff800252bda1 
0xffffff810b84b550 : 0xffffff8002617cc2 
0xffffff810b84b710 : 0xffffff8002634b73 
0xffffff810b84b730 : 0xffffff7f8447c6ff 
0xffffff810b84b890 : 0xffffff800276f2b7 
0xffffff810b84b8f0 : 0xffffff8002762dd6 
0xffffff810b84b990 : 0xffffff800274e5b8 
0xffffff810b84bbd0 : 0xffffff800274f190 
0xffffff810b84bf50 : 0xffffff8002a4ba86 
0xffffff810b84bfb0 : 0xffffff8002635376 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.autofs(3.0)[B2C3E47B-4270-3D65-86AF-1AA7EB8B509B]@0xffffff7f84478000->0xffffff7f84480fff
            dependency: com.apple.kext.triggers(1.0)[F36ADAAF-ADCB-3EE7-B040-4B7C45A1CCEB]@0xffffff7f83137000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: osascript

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6916749187271
last loaded kext at 999801727765: com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.7.5 (addr 0xffffff7f84df5000, size 94208)
last unloaded kext at 1192675342225: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f84dd7000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  263.9.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B09, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: My Passport 0748
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: USB to Serial-ATA bridge
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: For others - General advice on troubleshooting kernel panics is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both case I would pinpoint the Soundflower. (disable it or reinstall it).

In first case it was your Bluetooth, and in the second looks like some FF add on script.

Case 1:  `last unloaded kext at 117493781525860: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7fb1e00000, size 16384) loaded kexts: com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower 1.5.1`

Case 2: `last unloaded kext at 117493781525860: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7fb1e00000, size 16384) loaded kexts: com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower 1.5.1`

As you can see in both cases = Soundflower :)

Needless to say your Soundflower version is bit out of date, it should be 1.6.5 at least.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response - that certainly explains it. I never thought to look for the latest version of Soundflower - it's about time I upgraded!

Comment: Note- even the new beta Soundflowe still has issues with Yosemite. I had my first kernel panic in years recently- resolved to Soundflowe:-(

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't use it that often, so will probably just uninstall it, in that case.

Comment: My mid 2012 has the same issue, but I do not use Soundflower. I am guessing Apple changed something about their Kernel Extensions...

Comment: Update: Had another Kernel Panic, documented [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192485/new-kernel-panic-on-yosemite).