# New Kernel Panic on Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, kernel-panic

I previously had recurrent kernel panics (documented [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182830/kernel-panics-during-and-after-10-10-3-update)), which [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) kindly traced back to Soundflower. I uninstalled the software, and the problem seemed to be resolved. However I had another kernel panic today, after waking the computer from sleep. I wonder if anyone can provide some insight based on the log. Thanks for reading.

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff8001a17cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f82ec000e, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffffff87c6d445, CR3: 0x0000000244d1103c, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff80135e4200, RBX: 0xffffff80135f2200, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff80135f2200
RSP: 0xffffff810b36b2a0, RBP: 0xffffff810b36b2a0, RSI: 0x0000000000001000, RDI: 0xffffff7f82ec42e6
R8:  0xffffff810b36b500, R9:  0xffffff8013573000, R10: 0xffffff80135f2200, R11: 0x0000000000000202
R12: 0xffffff7f8316fd8f, R13: 0x0000000000001000, R14: 0xffffff8013573000, R15: 0x0000000000001000
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff7f82ec000e, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffffff87c6d445, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x3

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810b36af50 : 0xffffff800192bda1 
0xffffff810b36afd0 : 0xffffff8001a17cc2 
0xffffff810b36b190 : 0xffffff8001a34b73 
0xffffff810b36b1b0 : 0xffffff7f82ec000e 
0xffffff810b36b2a0 : 0xffffff7f82ec3979 
0xffffff810b36b2f0 : 0xffffff7f82ec4071 
0xffffff810b36b330 : 0xffffff7f82ec3d9d 
0xffffff810b36b430 : 0xffffff7f82e72297 
0xffffff810b36b7b0 : 0xffffff7f82e77218 
0xffffff810b36b850 : 0xffffff7f82dcc534 
0xffffff810b36b8a0 : 0xffffff7f82dcf674 
0xffffff810b36b8f0 : 0xffffff7f82de2333 
0xffffff810b36b950 : 0xffffff7f82d0ff24 
0xffffff810b36b990 : 0xffffff7f82dcc9a6 
0xffffff810b36ba90 : 0xffffff7f82d58660 
0xffffff810b36bb40 : 0xffffff7f82539a04 
0xffffff810b36bb70 : 0xffffff8001ed6d0e 
0xffffff810b36bbd0 : 0xffffff7f82539a6b 
0xffffff810b36bc20 : 0xffffff7f82d584ba 
0xffffff810b36bc70 : 0xffffff8001ba1f83 
0xffffff810b36bcc0 : 0xffffff8001b9a971 
0xffffff810b36bd90 : 0xffffff8001b9ab4f 
0xffffff810b36bdc0 : 0xffffff8001df296a 
0xffffff810b36be00 : 0xffffff8001dae84b 
0xffffff810b36be30 : 0xffffff8001ded7c4 
0xffffff810b36bf50 : 0xffffff8001e4ba86 
0xffffff810b36bfb0 : 0xffffff8001a35376 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[247581D8-DFC5-3AAE-B079-3D13F5514C2B]@0xffffff7f82531000->0xffffff7f8255cfff
         com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(730.60)[FF170A59-6AC0-3DB7-802D-B0796B2E9FE6]@0xffffff7f82d03000->0xffffff7f82dadfff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[0CB1D8BD-9EB7-3A02-8274-BCBB852B55B4]@0xffffff7f825f8000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[247581D8-DFC5-3AAE-B079-3D13F5514C2B]@0xffffff7f82531000
         com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360(930.37.3)[3F2DB810-F6E9-3A4B-AE4F-0D4AAB0DE13F]@0xffffff7f82db6000->0xffffff7f8339bfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[195AAC0A-1684-36C5-8951-6E46376023DD]@0xffffff7f82a08000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(730.60)[FF170A59-6AC0-3DB7-802D-B0796B2E9FE6]@0xffffff7f82d03000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f82124000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[247581D8-DFC5-3AAE-B079-3D13F5514C2B]@0xffffff7f82531000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: airportd

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001700000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 84228247938150
last loaded kext at 44205542984093: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f841b3000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 44278961864119: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f841b3000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  263.9.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B09, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: My Passport 0748
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Edit: Here's the [console log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnyjx5l2qkisl1i/All%20Messages.log?dl=0) around the relevant timestamp (21:57:18).

Edit: Here are some [more logs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30psfol54ce8ryl/All%20Messages2.log?dl=0) and an [EtreCheck report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pj53evkbqlggdve/EtreCheck.txt?dl=0).

Comment: Here again, we would need your Console log at the time stamp of interest (wake up) to see what was happening. In the panic report it does say it had problems with the "BSD process name corresponding to current thread: airportd" which is your Networking app/hardware. Normally that would not lead to Kernel panic but rater inform you of having problems to connect to network, so give us the Console log.

Comment: Thank you..reading it...unfortunately you stopped when it gets interesting :) 20/06/2015 21:57:19.155 DumpPanic[54] Saved panic report for kernel to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2015-06-20-215719_Wittgenstein.panic......can you look that report up and tell us what is it about. Also do you have any bluetooth device connected?

Comment: I would suggest you use the EtreCheck app to get a profile of your system.  http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck it is a non invasive method for possible troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks - I've added some more from the log and an EtreCheck report. The panic report brings up the report in my initial post. The only bluetooth device connected is an apple Magic Mouse.

Comment: OK, reading a lots of stuff, so far there is a indication the BT hub/mouse is making some problems, try operating without for a while.

Comment: What is the indication?

Comment: try this to find out what is causing it copy following in your Terminal and run it "syslog -k Sender kernel -k Message CSeq 'n Cause: -' | tail | awk '/:/{$4=""; print}' | pbcopy" ...The output is in the clipboard...so just use TextEdit and paste it there.

Answer (score 1):

My thought:
The computer went to sleep and was unable to Wake for Network Access causing a kernel panic related to the the IONetworking drivers.

Potential solutions:
Delete the sleepimage file found in the

```
/var/vm/
```

Folder

Delete the contents within

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/
```

This will delete the wifi network information from the computer. For example, the password to you home network.

Restart your computer after removing these files. Go to System Preferences > Sharing, add your preferred Sharing name I.e. Xxx's iMac

I believe this will take care of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 'Wake for network access' is unchecked in System Preferences. Could this still be the problem?

Comment: I would say these steps will be a good troubleshooting step to isolate.